# Illustrator: after opening an svg, how do I make all used colors into swatches?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, swatches

I opened an svg in illustrator.  My swatches panel was empty.  I want it to have all the colors used in the svg.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Select > Select All`
- From the **Swatch Panel Menu** choose `Add Selected Colors`

Or...

- Click the `New Color Group` button at the bottom of the **Swatch Panel**. (The little folder-looking button.)

You'll be presented with a pop up that looks similar to this...

[image]

When you click `OK`, you'll have a swatch color group in the **Swatch Panel**.

---

The difference is primarily in the ability to add swatches for *tints* and/or convert the added swatches to Global swatches (as seen in the pop up dialog window.)